# (Vue) beforeRouteUpdate with async/await?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

```js
let fetchData = async function() {
  return $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
}

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const cComponent = {
  data() {
    return {
      fetchedData: null
    }
  },
  template: `<div>{{$route.params.id+': '}}{{fetchedData}}</div>`,
  async beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    let data = await fetchData();
    next(vm => vm.fetchedData = data);
  },

  async beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    console.log("beforeRouteUpdate");
    let data = await fetchData();
    this.fetchedData = data;
    next();
  }

}
const routes = [{
  path: "/path/:id",
  component: cComponent,
}]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes,
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="   https://unpkg.com/vue-router@3.5.1/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <router-link to="/path/1">An URL</router-link>
  <router-link to="/path/2">Another one</router-link>
  <router-link to="/path/3">And another one</router-link>
  <router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>
</div>
```

This is the fetch function that retrieves data from a server:

```
let fetchPage = async (route) => {
    return $.get('route');
}
```

This is my `beforeRouteUpdate` navigation guard, which `fetchedData` property of the Vue instance (declared in *data* option beforehand) does not changes.

```
async beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    this.fetchedData = await fetchPage(to.path);
     //fetchData is not changed while changing route param
    next();
}
```

The `next()` callback is activated at the end (URL does change), but `this.fetchedData` shows `null` in Vue DevTools (initializing value).

On the other hand, if I do the same thing with `async/await` in `beforeRouteEnter` hook, everything works perfectly.

```
async beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    let data = await fetchPage(to.path);
    next(app => app.fetchedData = data); //fetchedData  has fetched data as supposed.
},
```

I tried replacing `this` with `app` just like in `beforeRouteEnter` hook. But there's still no result.

What am I missing? Is this the best practice with guard hooks and how should I use them better? (ignore `Exception` handling part)

---

Updated: SPA experience for code snippet on StackOverflow is kinda not perfect so you better try using my provided JS ([here](https://jsfiddle.net/HuyPham55/zL59cax7/26)). It has the same problem but I simplified it.

---

**Versions**

Vue 2.6

VueRouter 3.5

Comment: It's done the way you did it. Callback function with trial and error because hooks are used in strictly determined way. The whole thing is described here https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards . It's unknown why the property is null in your case. That it's null and not undefined suggests that there is some value. Double check how fetchPage works and try to mock it if necessary.

Comment: @EstusFlask  It says that `beforeRouteEnter is the only guard that supports passing a callback to next`, how am I supposed to use a callback within it?. Also, I forgot to mention that `null` is the initializing value and there is data returned back as checked in `Network` tab (updated)

Comment: A callback is used in beforeRouteEnter the way you did it. The question cannot be answered in general because in general it's done the way you did it, and it should work. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem and show where you have wrong values. Consider clarifying this part, "fetchData is not changed while changing route param". But you already set fetchData on previous navigation in beforeRouteEnter, so it cannot be null after beforeRouteUpdate, unless it was assigned to null with `await fetchPage(to.path)`.

Comment: @EstusFlask Sorry for late reply, I was struggling with Stackoverflow's embeded snippet, so I added the fiddle.

Comment: @HuyPhạm Your code works as expected but it might not be the way you want. Since you put the `key` in `router-view` when the key changed the new component will be mounted but your `beforeRouteUpdate` is the hook of old component which will be destroy soon. You just update `fetchedData` of old component not the new one. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnjmtqo3/).

Comment: @User28 Looks good to me. Sounds counter intuitive but actually the problem. Would you mind putting it as an answer as well?

Comment: It's as User 28 said., I guess it's that issue, https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/974 . That you give different key doesn't mean that router lifecycle is retriggered, because the route is the same. It causes view instance to be renewed though. Since you rely on update hook, you need to not change a key on param change, likely should be `:key="$route.matched[0] && $route.matched[0].path`.